# Reusing data used for making prediction for training

Tags: machine-learning

I wanted to understand and make sure that the following way of making predictions and training model is correct:

I have a model $M$ and it makes a prediction on data $X$ today, tomorrow the model retrains and in training data it will include the yesterday's data $X$ and so on.

Is there anything that could be wrong with this approach, I know that the other way is wrong i.e. I should not use the training data for prediction but is the vice-versa also wrong.

Comment: This is known as expanding (or recursive) estimation window and is common in time series forecasting. It should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing wrong if you can handle the computational expense introduced by frequent retrainings. This doesn’t introduduce data leakage.